# is there any possibility to change fields dynamically

Tags: ios5, ios4

Is there any possibility to change the fields like textfield to textview when user click the edit button to change fields.... pls tell me any possibilities

Comment: Yes, there are. What did you deduce from reading their documentation? (you DID read those, right?)

Comment: pls send the documentation link if you have

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head - dynamically swap to a textview when editing, and when done editing put the text into a textfield and put it back in the view.

Try that and then come back if you have any trouble with coding it.

Comment: i have  ten field, for example first field ->label(name:) textfield. second -> label(overall) segmented controller with option good and fair. user click the edit button and change the segmented controller to textfield. its possible.